# What cameras are the amaro, mayfair, walden instagram filters based on / inspired by?

Tags: instagram

I'm drawn the most to the Amar, Mayfair and Walden filters. I would like to know which real cameras they are based on, or inspired by, if any?

Comment: Your edit has made this two separate questions - please keep each post to just one question. I'll revert the edit, but feel free to ask the second question in a separate post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, they're not based on any camera. Kevin Systrom, the co-founder and ex-CEO of Instagram, said the following in [How does Instagram choose names for their filters?](http://www.quora.com/How-does-Instagram-choose-names-for-their-filters) on Quora:

> I wish that I could say it's more interesting - but often it has to do with the inspiration for the filter... a type of film, a photo we've seen, or simply what we were doing at the time.

For the video filters, [AllThingsD](http://allthingsd.com/20130621/how-instagram-named-its-new-set-of-video-filters/) has the details, but there's no one theme.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog post that tries to reverse engineer the filters into camera/film combinations: http://blog.1000memories.com/97-old-school-instagram-filters-using-vintage-cameras-and-film

Unfortunately, it doesn't have Amaro or Mayfair listed. And for what it's worth, my personal experience with a Yashica Mat-124G with Velvia 100 didn't come out looking the way they said it would:
[image]

Comment: As noted above, I've changed this question back to the original meaning of which cameras the filters are based on, so this answer unfortunately looks a bit out of place now. Hopefully the original poster will ask a new question in which case this will be a good answer :-)

Comment: "And for what it's worth, my personal experience with a Yashica Mat-124G with Velvia 100 didn't come out looking the way they said it would"  Just curious - what were you expecting?